# Ensuring performance of sketching/streaming algorithm (countSketch)

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, stream, scipy

I have implemented what is know as a *countSketch* in Python (page 17: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1411.4357.pdf) but my implementation is currently lacking in performance.
The algorithm is to compute the product `SA` where

- `A` is an `n x d` matrix,
- `S` is `m x n` matrix defined as follows:
  For every column of `S` uniformly at random select a row (hash bucket) from the `m` rows and for that given row, uniformly at random select +1 or -1.
  So S is a matrix with exactly one nonzero in every column and otherwise all zero.

My intention is to compute `SA` in a *streaming* fashion by reading the entries of `A`. The idea for my implementation is as follows: observe a sequence of triples `(i,j,A_ij)` and return a sequence `(h(i), j, s(i)A_ij)` where:

- `h(i)` is a hash bucket (row of matrix chosen uniformly at random from the `m` possible rows of `S`
- `s(i)` is the random sign function as described above.

I have assumed that the matrix is in *row order* so that the first row of `A` arrives in its entirety before the next row of `A` arrives because this limits the number of calls I need to select a random bucket or the need to use a hash library.
I have also assumed that the number of nonzero entries (or the length of the input stream) is known so that I can efficiently encode the iteration.

My problem is that the matrix should compute `(1+error)*||Ax||^2 <= ||SAx||^2 <= (1+error)*||Ax||^2` and also have the difference in frobenius norms between `A^T S^T S A` and `A^T A` being small.  However, while my implementation for the first condition seems to be true, the latter is consistently too small.
I was wondering if there is an obvious reason for this that I am missing because it seems to be underestimating the latter quantity.

I am open to feedback on changing the code if there are obvious improvements to be made.

nb. If you don't want to run using `numba` then just comment out the import and the function decorator and it will run in standard numpy/scipy.

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.random as npr
import scipy.sparse as sparse
from scipy.sparse import coo_matrix
import numba
from numba import jit


@jit(nopython=True) # comment this if want just numpy
def countSketch(input_rows, input_data,
                      input_nnz,
                      sketch_size, seed=None):
   '''
   input_rows: row indices for data (can be repeats)
   input_data: values seen in row location,
   input_nnz : number of nonzeroes in the data (can replace with
   len(input_data) but avoided here for speed)
   sketch_size: int
   seed=None : random seed
   '''
   hashed_rows = np.empty(input_rows.shape,dtype=np.int32)
   current_row = 0
   hash_val = npr.choice(sketch_size)
   sign_val = npr.choice(np.array([-1.0,1.0]))
   #print(hash_val)
   hashed_rows[0] = hash_val
   #print(hash_val)
   for idx in np.arange(input_nnz):
       print(idx)
       row_id = input_rows[idx]
       data_val = input_data[idx]
       if row_id == current_row:
           hashed_rows[idx] = hash_val
           input_data[idx] = sign_val*data_val
       else:
           # make new hashes
           hash_val = npr.choice(sketch_size)
           sign_val = npr.choice(np.array([-1.0,1.0]))
           hashed_rows[idx] = hash_val
           input_data[idx] = sign_val*data_val
   return hashed_rows, input_data

def sort_row_order(input_data):
   sorted_row_column = np.array((input_data.row,
                                 input_data.col,
                                 input_data.data))

   idx  = np.argsort(sorted_row_column[0])
   sorted_rows = np.array(sorted_row_column[0,idx], dtype=np.int32)
   sorted_cols = np.array(sorted_row_column[1,idx], dtype=np.int32)
   sorted_data = np.array(sorted_row_column[2,idx], dtype=np.float64)
   return sorted_rows, sorted_cols, sorted_data


if __name__=="__main__":
   import time
   from tabulate import tabulate

   matrix = sparse.random(1000, 50, 0.1)
   x = np.random.randn(matrix.shape[1])
   true_norm = np.linalg.norm(matrix@x,ord=2)**2
   tidy_data =  sort_row_order(matrix)

   sketch_size = 300
   start = time.time()
   hashed_rows, sketched_data = countSketch(tidy_data[0],\
                                            tidy_data[2], matrix.nnz,sketch_size)
   duration_slow = time.time() - start
   S_A = sparse.coo_matrix((sketched_data, (hashed_rows,matrix.col)))
   approx_norm_slow = np.linalg.norm(S_A@x,ord=2)**2
   rel_error_slow = approx_norm_slow/true_norm
   #print("Sketch time: {}".format(duration_slow))
   start = time.time()
   hashed_rows, sketched_data = countSketch(tidy_data[0],\
                                           tidy_data[2], matrix.nnz,sketch_size)
   duration = time.time() - start
   #print("Sketch time: {}".format(duration))
   S_A = sparse.coo_matrix((sketched_data, (hashed_rows,matrix.col)))
   approx_norm = np.linalg.norm(S_A@x,ord=2)**2
   rel_error = approx_norm/true_norm
   #print("Relative norms: {}".format(approx_norm/true_norm))
   print(tabulate([[duration_slow, rel_error_slow, 'Yes'],
                   [duration, rel_error, 'No']],
                   headers=['Sketch Time', 'Relative Error', 'Dry Run'],
                   tablefmt='orgtbl'))
```

Comment: "... the latter is consistently too small_" does that mean it is not working correctly?

Comment: Should `(1+error)*||Ax||^2 <= ||SAx||^2 <= (1+error)*||Ax||^2` read *(1 **-** error)\*∥Ax∥² ≤ ∥SAx∥² ≤ (1+error)\*∥Ax∥²*?

Answer (score 0):

as suggested by @SamOnela, code not working is off-topic. for your performance issue, you can group your calls to `choice` at the beginning of your function

```
   hash_vals = npr.choice(sketch_size, input_nnz)
   sign_vals = npr.choice(np.array([-1.0,1.0]), input_nnz)
```

and use it later in your code this way:

```
       hashed_rows[idx] = hash_vals[idx]
       input_data[idx] = sign_vals[idx]*data_val
```